# Strange permission denied error message

Tags: files, filesystems, tcpdump

Here is what I'm trying to do (CentOS 7):

```
root@serv02 # /usr/sbin/tcpdump -nn -i eno16780032 -s 0 udp port 53 -w /var/opt/A.pcap -C 100 -W 30
tcpdump: /var/opt/A.pcap00: Permission denied
```

I'm running this as root and the file system is not full. I just don't understand why `tcpdump` does not create the file.

The command worked fine without `-C` and looked like `-C` caused `tcpdump` to drop privileges, but why?

Comment: This SF Q&A nails your issue - https://serverfault.com/questions/478636/tcpdump-out-pcap-permission-denied. It's what Siva shows in his A'er but shows how to triage this issue with `strace` and explains why it's happening.

Answer (score 2):

From `man` page :

> `-Z`     Drops privileges (if root) and changes user ID to user and the group ID to the primary group of user.
>
> This behavior is enabled by default (-Z tcpdump), and can be disabled by -Z root.

By default, `tcpdump` is dropping privileges to the 'tcpdump' user. So mention the root user in command and try:

```
 $ tcpdump -nn -i eno16780032 -s 0 udp port 53 -w /var/opt/A.pcap -C 100 -W 30 -Z root
```

Comment: Hmm, I've never heard of this, good catch.

Comment: @SivaPrasath man page on CentOS 7 is different to yours. -z is postrotate command. Did not say anything of dropping privileges.